# Time based php script

Tags: php, time

Say I want a php script the run the function itstime() every hour. Other than setting up a cron job on the server how can I do this?

Or is this not possible because php scripts need to be opened to be ran?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no other way that I am aware of. Is there a specific reason you cannot use a cronjob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some web services doing this, for example

- http://www.setcronjob.com/
- http://www.webcron.org/

Answer (score 0):

The only other way than to use cron or a webservice that runs cron is to use a workaround; each time the site is loaded by a user, check if it is more than an hour since last time and if it is, run the function. Not very pretty though..

Answer (score -1):

you can write a daemon in php, although it's overkill to cron, you can
[google](http://www.google.com/search?&q=php%20daemon) for it